# Trying to use multiple AS, but I'm getting: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using 3 tables from my database which I read data for my rank (top15) table. I'm trying to fill one 'tr' with only one query (using multiple Aliases), but I'm stuck here:

My last try was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(mapname),
(SELECT his_time FROM primekz_records 
    WHERE primekz_records.id=$player_id AND his_aa = 10 AND tp > 0) AS nub10,
(SELECT his_time FROM primekz_records
    WHERE primekz_records.id=$player_id    AND his_aa = 10 AND tp = 0) AS pro10 
FROM primekz_records

JOIN primekz_players ON primekz_records.id=primekz_players.id 
JOIN primekz_maps ON primekz_maps.mid=primekz_records.mid 

WHERE primekz_players.id=$player_id
```

Tables are structured:

```
primekz_players( id, steamid, name ...)
primekz_maps( mid, mapname )
primekz_records( id, mid, his_time, his_aa, tp, ... ) <-- this means one ID(player) can be max 4 times for one mid (map), variations are: his_aa (10/100), tp (0/more)
```

If I try with only one alias I get this result, which is totally wrong (see Noob100 column).

https://i.snag.gy/tHpUK8.jpg

Does it have something to do with ROW_NUMBER() + 4x AS ?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.

Comment: Ok now i get it. But what could be a solution for this? Doing multiple queries (with only one AS) ?

Comment: . . Pretty difficult for anyone to say, because you haven't provided sample data, desired results, or an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Select multiple rows from SQL Table -> print 'his_time' from one row into one column of the table (pro10 for example). Second found row should print same column ('his_time') result to table's noob10. 3rd query result (again 'his_time' row) should go to Pro100 table column, and last, 4th result needs to go Noob100 (but in primekz_records all these rows must have the same 'mid') i hope its clear now...+image: https://i.snag.gy/pMuzIO.jpg